# MVC: after adding custom route, default route is ignored?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

In my routeConfig I added a custom route on the top of default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "appointmentandattendee",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{appointmentId}/{attendeeId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Response", action = "Index", appointmentId = UrlParameter.Optional, attendeeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

So, for this action

```
public ActionResult Index(Guid appointmentId, Guid attendeeId)
{
   return Content("Hello");
}
```

routing looks like

```
http://localhost/Response/Index/96de7851-49f6-4b69-8a58-2bea39bd466e/7d4fe8ed-7dae-e311-be8f-001c42aef0b2
```

but now the routing with name **Default** is ignored

for example:
In my Appointment controller with some action and parameter as id I was expecting Default route to be used, but it doesn't
So, for this action in `AppointmentController`

```
public ActionResult Test(Guid id)
{          
    return Content("Hello");
}
```

routing looks like

```
localhost:/Appointment/Test?id=96de7851-49f6-4b69-8a58-2bea39bd466e
```

Why is that?
Shouldn't it be using the default routing in this case?

Comment: It's because you declared the `appointmentId` and `attendeeId` parameters to be optional. This is now the most general route in your route list. Are you sure you want them to be optional? Isn't it their purpose to be always passed to your action?

Comment: Even if I did `defaults: new { controller = "Response", action = "Index", appointmentId = "", attendeeId = "" }` it didn't work. What I ended up doing is  `url: "Response/{appointmentId}/{attendeeId}"` So the controller should be response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your route `appointmentandattendee` overrides your default route.

try this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "appointmentandattendee",
    url: "Response/{action}/{appointmentId}/{attendeeId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Response", action = "Index", appointmentId = UrlParameter.Optional, attendeeId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I specified URL with first part as `Response`, default controller remains `controller = "Response"`. Now your route not as general as it was before.

Comment: can I have multiple defaults? so for example this only works when action name is Index. Lets say I have another method with two parameters with appointmentId and attendeeId, how do I make this route work in that case?

Comment: if your url is /Response/AnotherMethod/ it will much this route.

Comment: but I have set the url as `url: "Response/{appointmentId}/{attendeeId}"` just to hide the action. Now in this case the another method doesn't work. I'll probably have to mention it to use the anothermethod as well?

Comment: Please provide the URL you wish to have

Comment: Can I invite you to chat? so that I can explain properly?

Comment: @Biplov13 MVC Routing goes from top to bottom and picks the first route that matches, even if its not the best choice. You want to place your routes in order of specificity. If your default route is the first on the list, it'll never even check the other routes. Put your most specific routes first, and the more general ones last. "Can I have multiple defaults" - I hope this answers your question.